# Generate header dependencies for cuda files

Tags: cuda, g++, makefile

I would like to generate the header dependencies for my CUDA source files to include it into a makefile.

I tried to use the following code:

```
g++ -MM my_cuda_file.cu
```

This is working for .cpp and for .h files, but for .cu files I just get the following error:

```
g++: warning: my_cuda_file.cu: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

How can I make it work?

I tried the following codes too, but neither of them working:

```
nvcc -MM my_cuda_file.cu
nvcc -Xcompiler "-MM" my_cuda_file.cu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the CUDA compiler driver nvcc reference guide:

> 2.4. Supported Phases
>
> ```
>    make dependency generation `-M`
> ```
>
> 3.2.1. Options for Specifying the Compilation Phase
>
> ```
>     --generate-dependencies    -M     Generate for the one .c/.cc/.cpp/.cxx/.cu 
>                                       input file (more than one are not allowed 
>                                       in this step) a dependency file that can 
>                                       be included in a make file.
> ```
>
> 3.2.2. File and Path Specifications
>
> ```
>      --output-directory        -odir  Specify the directory of the output file. 
>                                       This option is intended for letting the
>                                       dependency generation step (--generate-dependencies) 
>                                       generate a rule that defines the target 
>                                       object file in the proper directory.
> ```
>
> 3.2.5. Options for Guiding the Compiler Driver
>
> ```
>      --dependency-drive-prefix -ddp   On Windows platforms, when generating
>                                         dependency files (option -M), all file names 
>                                         must be converted to whatever the used 
>                                         instance of make will recognize. Some 
>                                         instances of make have trouble with the 
>                                         colon in absolute paths in native Windows                     
>                                         format, which depends on the environment in 
>                                         which this make instance has been compiled. 
>                                         Use -ddp /cygwin/ for a CygWin make, and -ddp / 
>                                         for Mingw. Or leave these file names in native
>                                         Windows format by specifying nothing.
> ```

In Chapter 5 of that guide you could find some usage examples.

Comment: Should I use `-MT` for the generated file or `-o` to specify it as a target?